# Emitting a Matrix from a mapper in Hadoop

Tags: java, dictionary, hadoop, reduce

I am new to Hadoop map reduce, I wanted to know that there is some outputformat type which can allow me to emit a matrix (2d array) directly from the mapper (without converting to 1d).

I plan to include this in my Btech project.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at: http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/TwoDArrayWritable.html
I guess that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You want to emit only a `value` as 2D array you can use `TwoDArrayWritable`

If you need to emit a `key` too as matrix- you need to Implement a [Custom Writable Class](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/hadoop/9780596521974/serialization/id3548156)

Hope that you got an idea.